# Ubuntu doesn't boot normally after manual installing of X.org

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, boot

I tried to compile and install X.org (for a single card/multiseat in [this](http://www.amxl.com/c/single-graphics-card-multi-seat-ubuntu-linux) tutorial) by getting source from [here](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/src/xserver/xorg-server-1.9.3.tar.bz2) and installing it by:

```
./configure --enable-kdrive --enable-xephyr --enable-xfake --enable-xfbdev --enable-kdrive-kbd --enable-kdrive-mouse --enable-kdrive-evdev --enable-glx-tls
make
sudo make install
```

after this Ubuntu freezes in boot on the Ubuntu logo and doesn't boot up!
**Note**: it boots in recovery mode and X starts by using `startx` from terminal (in recovery mode) ; it just doesn't start normally!
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

What is the problem?
How can I fix it?

Comment: could you upload the X.log and dmesg logs? It sounds as if the hardware discovery doesn't work

Comment: @Hartmut: currently i checked boot output; lightdm fails!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you generated an xorg.conf file? Try booting into recovery mode, and running this command:

```
$ Xorg -configure
```

That will create an xorg.conf file at `/root/xorg.conf.new`. Edit the file as needed and copy it to `/etc/xorg.conf`. Reboot and see if it works.

If that doesn't work, try generating an xorg.conf file using `nvidia-xconfig`. You will also probably need to reconfigure the driver. try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install module-assistant nvidia-kernel-common nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-settings nvidia-xconfig
sudo m-a auto-install nvidia-kernel${VERSION}-source
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Comment: it gives `Missing output drivers. Configuration failed` !!

Comment: Excellent! Edit your Device section to give the right drivers ('radeon' for ATI, 'nouveau' for nvidia). Also install them if necessary. See the Arch Wiki [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg](here) for more information.

Comment: But there is no xorg.conf to edit! `Xorg -configure` gives this error!

Comment: Ah, have you installed the drivers for your card? What is your card?

Comment: before compiling Xorg , yes (on previous X) ; it is nVidia 210

Comment: See my updated answer @4r1y4n.

Answer (score 1):

Try to press "End" wile showing the logo to see where it stops so we can have a better idea on what to do next, but xorg.log might tell you something too.

Comment: It fastly shows outputs and clears screen then it prompt for username (TTY terminal login)

Comment: Terminal login? Hum, seems that X is not starting at all, but I guess you could check that with ps or top.

Are you sure you've setup "/usr/bin/startup-X':" script (described in the tutorial correctly)?

Comment: currently i checked boot output; lightdm fails!

Comment: you could try to do a sudo apt-get update and reinstall lightdm after that. 

Or maybe even instal gdm and see if you can get the login screen.

Comment: ....
But the xorg.log must mention something more...
Make sure you have the latest graphic drivers, and check if for instance you have an intel, but nvidia grapichs are instaled, I had problems with lightgm once because of that...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 used to refuse to boot X, when `xorg.conf` was present (it was left from 9.10). I removed it and it booted ok.

Comment: tried but no effect!